# Java: How convert a List of Object to List of String?

Tags: java

I have a class named `Pessoa`

```
Classe Pessoa {
  Id Integer,
  Nome String
}
```

And in another part I have a list of objects of this class:

```
List<Pessoa> pessoas = getPessoas();
```

The above code works properly, but I need to transform it into a `List<String>`, where it only includes `Nome` field of class `Pessoa`.

How can I do that?

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot . I'm using it on Android and Android uses Java 6.

Comment: Create a `List<String>`, loop over your original list and add the name of each person in the list you created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it easily with Java 8 Streams :

```
List<String> names = pessoas.stream().map(Pessoa::getName).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This is assuming your `Pessoa` class has a `getName()` method returning a `String`.

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot . I'm using it on Android and Android uses Java 6.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the attribute Nome is public and "pessoas" is your list of Pessoa:

```
public List<String> getNomes(List<Pessoa> pessoasList) {
            List<String> nomes = new ArrayList<>();

            for(Pessoa pessoaObj : pessoasList){
                    nomes.add(pessoaObj.nome)
            }    

            return nomes;
```

}

If you didn't understand that for loop, I suggest for you to search a little about that loop syntax. It works very well for lists. Simple and easy.

Edit:
As Eran said, it is easier using Streams, **if using Java SDK 8 or newer**:

```
List<String> names = pessoas.stream().map(Pessoa::getName).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Or, using Kotlin:

```
val names = pessoas.map{it.name}
```